# ogr2ogr/python overwrite PostGIS table

Tags: python, ogr, ogr2ogr

Using ogr2ogr command line I can overwrite or append to an existing PostGIS table like:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL"-overwrite PG:"host=myserver port=54321 user=user dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" C:/Temp/my.shp
```

Next, I would like to incorporate this logic into a python script.  I've found some useful sites, however I'm not finding any examples using these methods.

[Open Source RS/GIS Python Week 1](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides1.pdf)

[PostGIS OGR Examples](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiOGR)

[Append a shapefile to a postgis table using the GDAL/OGR Python interface](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-July/029283.html)

How do you overwrite or append to a PostGIS table using ogr2ogr commands in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer using python GDAL bindings but I have used the python [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to call the GDAL command line utility to batch load Shapefiles into into postGIS. Something like this would work:

```
for shapefile in shp_list:
    program = "C:\Path\to\GDAL"
    command = 'ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL"-overwrite PG:"host=myserver port=54321 user=user dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" %s' shapefile
    input_command = [command]
    command_run = subprocess.call([program, input_command])
    if command_run == 0:
        print "Its worked!!"
    else:
        print "Table exists so appending"
        input_command = [command]
        command_run = subprocess.call([program, input_command])
        command = 'ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL"-overwrite PG:"host=myserver port=54321 user=user dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" C:/Temp/my.shp'
        command_run = subprocess.call([program, input_command])
```

If the ogr2ogr command fails (because the table already exists) then a second command is tried this time using the append option (-f).

Its not fool proof but does the job if you can be sure you wont be getting any other errors from the command line.