# Gdal ogr2ogr update a PostGIS table without breaking views and relations

Tags: postgis, gdal, shapefile, postgresql, ogr2ogr

## Context

I'm trying to update a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)+[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) table from an [ESRI Shapefile](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) using the [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) tool from [gdal](https://gdal.org/).
The Shapefile is being updated from external sources on a regular basis.
I don't want to *append* its content, I prefer starting again from scratch.

This is the command I run for the moment;

```bash
ogr2ogr \
  -lco OVERWRITE=yes \
  -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI \
  -nln vector_data.lines \
  -f "PostgreSQL" \
     PG:"host=localhost user=username dbname=my_database" \ 
  -a_srs EPSG:4326 "${shapedir}/el_lines.shp"
```

## Issues

### 1:

I get this warning message:

```
Warning 1: Layer creation options ignored since an existing layer is
         being appended to.
```

And the features are being append to the table, hence doubling the number of rows.

### 2:

If I add the `-overwrite` option, features (i.e. records in the table) are being successfully updated, as I expect, but the downside is I lose all the [views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) and relations which have a link to the table I want to update. Needless to say I don't want to lose these views and relations.

## Question

How to wisely use `ogr2ogr` so that it builds the table as if it's newly created (such as the really first time I ran `ogr2ogr`), but while keeping all relations to this table in the database?

---

#### Related questions

- [ogr2ogr update failing to update shapefile int PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113486/ogr2ogr-update-failing-to-update-shapefile-int-postgis)
- [ogr2ogr/python overwrite PostGIS table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89493/ogr2ogr-python-overwrite-postgis-table)

---

#### Environment

PostgreSQL:

```
"PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, \
compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit"
```

PostGIS:

```
"2.4 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"
```

Gdal:

```
$ ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 2.4.0, released 2018/12/14
```

Comment: I've had good performance with loading to a new temporary table, then using INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE to drive changes to the existing table. A lot depends on whether you need to access the data from a concurrent process (e.g. a map service) or whether you can TRUNCATE and INSERT from the staged table after the initial load has taken place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html

> **Configuration Options**
>
> **OGR_TRUNCATE:**
>
> (GDAL >= 1.11) If set to “YES”, the content of the table will be first
>   erased with the SQL TRUNCATE command before inserting the first
>   feature. This is an alternative to using the -overwrite flag of
>   ogr2ogr, that avoids views based on the table to be destroyed. Typical
>   use case:

```
ogr2ogr -append PG:dbname=foo abc.shp --config OGR_TRUNCATE YES”
```

Comment: Is the `-append` flag mandatory? It sounds strange. In addition, why I cannot find the `--config` option in the man of `ogr2ogr` (https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)? Is it the same as the `-lco`? And how to use several `--config` options in a row?

Comment: Sounds logical as well `Append to existing layer instead of creating new`. Usage of Config options is documented in https://gdal.org/programs/vector_common_options.html. Options may be driver specific and documented in the driver manuals. Some are generic and documented in https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html and https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions. Config options are not the same as Layer Creation Options. There are also Open Options (-oo) that you may meet later when working with GDAL. Several options are used simply `--config option1 value --config option2 value`.

Comment: Ok. Actually, I noticed that the behavior is the same with or without the `-append` flag. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Yes, the flags should behave in the same way for all the drivers https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html but it is not always the case. For example Oracle driver has own options for setting SRID, DIM, OVERWRITE etc. and the common ogr2ogr options do not work.